# Help! My Ring & Post puzzle is stuck

Tags: three-dimensional, real

I have a fairly basic Ring and Wooden Post puzzle that I can usually solve.  However, at a recent family gathering (pre-Covid); the ring was tangled into a weird spot and I cannot figure it out.  Here is a link to what the puzzle actually is:  https://www.instructables.com/id/Eureka-Puzzle/

Here are some pictures of where the ring is stuck:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the position at the halfway mark on the "solution" video on the link you posted. Isn't it?

Comment: Looks like a good time to whip out a saw if you ask me

Comment: Agh, I recognize this position.  Unfortunately this puzzle gives me a headache and I cannot even remotely recall how to get out of this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just need to pass the disk of the "red bead" side through the slit and pull the ring up.